# Сокращение больших чисел с плавающей запятой до формата 12.342M или 1.023B в python

Tags: python

Пытаюсь написать функцию, что получает на вход длинное или не очень число и возвращает это же число, но сокращенное до формата, что указан в заголовке вопроса.

К примеру функция получает число 2 454 232, а возвращает его же, но в формате 2.454m.
Или 123 456 789 012 будет приведено к 123.456b.

Т.е. выводятся первые знаки числа(будь то 1, 10, 100 миллионов), затем ставится точка или запятая и после выводятся 3 последующие знака, будь то 001, 011, 111 или вообще 000(хотя возможно в ситуации с 000 можно было бы просто выводить первое число без точки, но это не так критично).

У меня получилось сокращение числа до самых первых знаков, чтобы выводилось к примеру 2m или 133b, но реализовать тысячные или миллионные после запятой у меня не выходит.

Знает ли кто-то как можно дополнить функцию, чтобы она корректно работала и возвращала числа после запятой?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
def shorten_number(number_to_shorten):
    str_number_to_shorten = str(number_to_shorten)
    if len(str_number_to_shorten) > 9 and len(str_number_to_shorten) <= 12:
        return str_number_to_shorten[:-9] + "B"

    elif len(str_number_to_shorten) >= 7 and len(str_number_to_shorten) <= 9:
        return str_number_to_shorten[:-6] + "M"

    else:
        return number_to_shorten
```

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, чуть больше примеров вводных и ожидаемых выходных данных .

Comment: да в общем то любые большие числа целые.
Как я уже раньше написал 2 454 232 будет приведено к 2.454m, а например более длинное число такое как 122 042 456 234 123 045 будет приведено к 122.042 и в конце буква от сокращенного названия этого числа.
Не обязательно заморачиваться с такими большими числами, достаточно сделать миллионные и можно миллиардные, мне этого хватит, я дальше сам разберусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант, но есть изъян.

```
def shorten_number(number_to_shorten):
    postfixes = ['m', 'b', ] # постфиксы для сокращенных чисел
    briefer_nums = [10**k for k in range(6, 6+3*len(postfixes), 3)] # список наших делителей
    for i in reversed(range(len(postfixes))):
        if number_to_shorten >= briefer_nums[i]:
            num = number_to_shorten/briefer_nums[i]
            return f'{num:.3f}{postfixes[i]}'
```

Собственно, изъян следующий: при попытке сократить число `123 456 789 012` получаем не `123.456b`, а `123.457b` из-за того, как работает округление.

---

Избавился от "изъяна"

```
def shorten_number(number_to_shorten):
    postfixes = ['m', 'b', ] # постфиксы для сокращенных чисел
    briefer_nums = [10**k for k in range(6, 6+3*len(postfixes), 3)] # список наших делителей
    for i in reversed(range(len(postfixes))):
        if number_to_shorten >= briefer_nums[i]:
            num = number_to_shorten / briefer_nums[i]
            int_part = int(num)
            float_part = str(num - int_part).split('.')[1][:3]
            return str(int_part) + '.' + float_part + postfixes[i]
```

---

Небольшая оптимизация расхода памяти и выделения целой и дробной частей:

```
def shorten_number(number_to_shorten):
    postfixes = ['m', 'b', ] # постфиксы для сокращенных чисел
    briefer_num = (10**(len(postfixes)+1))**3
    for i in reversed(range(len(postfixes))):
        if number_to_shorten >= briefer_num:
            num = number_to_shorten / briefer_num
            int_part, float_part = str(num).split('.')
            return int_part + '.' + float_part[:3] + postfixes[i]
        briefer_num //= 1000
```

Comment: оп, спасибо большое
Хотя мне и вариант с изъяном подошел бы, но без него вообще прекрасно.
Очень признателен

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_large_number(num: int | float):
    suffixes = ['K', 'M', 'B']
    if num < 1000:
        return str(num)
    num = float(num)
    for suffix in suffixes:
        num /= 1000
        if abs(num) < 1000:
            return '{:.1f}{}'.format(num, suffix)

    return '{:.1f}{}'.format(num, 'T')
```

столкнулся с похожей задачей
и накидал такое решение

Comment: решение из ответа выше мне не подходило, тк на малых входных значениях выдавало None, да и выглядит несколько переусложнённым

Comment: _выглядит несколько переусложнённым_ —прекрасный питоничный код. Советую внимательно изучить и всегда стараться подражать.